# Graphing a SVM hyperplane with Vector points, but vector points do not show up

Tags: graph, svm

Trying to graph my SVM model, and I can successfully graph the decision boundaries, however the data values that aid the decision boundary will not plot.
I keep getting a Key Error zero.

I am new to python so any information will help.

This is the code I used, when run the code displays a graph with the lines however the points do not show up.

```
    clf = SVC(gamma='auto', kernel ='linear')
    X1 = X_train.values
    Y1 = y_train.values
    # fit the above data in SVC
    clf.fit(X1,Y1)

    # plot the decision boundary ,data points,support vector etcv
    w = clf.coef_[0]
    a = -w[0] / w[1]

    xx = np.linspace(0,12)
    yy = a * xx - clf.intercept_[0] / w[1]
    y_neg = a * xx - clf.intercept_[0] / w[1] + 1
    y_pos = a * xx - clf.intercept_[0] / w[1] - 1
    plt.figure(1,figsize= (15, 10))
    plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k',
             label=f"Decision Boundary (y ={w[0]}x1  + {w[1]}x2  {clf.intercept_[0] })")
    plt.plot(xx, y_neg, 'b-.',
             label=f"Neg Decision Boundary (-1 ={w[0]}x1  + {w[1]}x2  {clf.intercept_[0] })")
    plt.plot(xx, y_pos, 'r-.',
             label=f"Pos Decision Boundary (1 ={w[0]}x1  + {w[1]}x2  {clf.intercept_[0] })")

    for i in range(3):
      if (Y1[i]==0):
          plt.scatter(X[i][0], X[i][1],color='red', marker='o', label='negative')
      else:
          plt.scatter(X[i][0], X[i][1],color='green', marker='x', label='positive')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example below I've overlaid some example data onto the decision function contours. I've also started off with a manual calculation, similar to yours, for plotting the linear decision boundary and margins (black lines in the left figure).

[image]

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#
# Make some test data
#
np.random.seed(3)
n_samples = 200
y = np.concatenate([np.ones(n_samples // 2), np.zeros(n_samples // 2)])
X = np.concatenate([-1 + np.random.randn(n_samples // 2, 2) / 4,
                    1 + np.random.randn(n_samples // 2, 2) / 2.5
                    ])

#Visualise data
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap='coolwarm', label='features')
ax.set(xlabel='feature 0', ylabel='feature 1')
ax_lims = ax.axis()

#
# Fit SVC
#
clf = SVC(gamma='auto', kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, y)

#Plot decision boundary assuming kernel is linear
# At the boundary:   w0 * x0 +  w1 * x1 + b = 0 
# At the +ve margin: w0 * x0 +  w1 * x1 + b = +1
if clf.kernel == 'linear': #or type(clf) is sklearn.svm.LinearSVC
    w0, w1 = clf.coef_[0]
    b = clf.intercept_
    margin = 1 / w1
    x0_leftright = ax_lims[0:2]
    decision_line = np.array(
        [-b/w1 - w0/w1 * x0 for x0 in x0_leftright]
    )

    ax.plot(x0_leftright, decision_line, 'k-', linewidth=10, label='decision boundary')
    ax.plot(x0_leftright, decision_line + margin, 'k:', linewidth=2, label='±1 margin')
    ax.plot(x0_leftright, decision_line - margin, 'k:', linewidth=2)

f.legend(ncol=3, loc='upper center')

#
# Get predictions and decision
# values over a grid in feature space.
#
# This helps visualise the decision boundary
# especially for non-linear kernels.
#
grid_res = 50
x0_grid, x1_grid = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(ax_lims[0], ax_lims[1], grid_res),
    np.linspace(ax_lims[2], ax_lims[3], grid_res)
)
all_grid_points = np.stack([x0_grid.ravel(), x1_grid.ravel()], axis=1)

predictions = clf.predict(all_grid_points).reshape(x0_grid.shape)
decision_vals = clf.decision_function(all_grid_points).reshape(x0_grid.shape)

#Flood fill with predicted class
ax.contourf(x0_grid, x1_grid, predictions, cmap='coolwarm', alpha=0.2, zorder=-1)

#add contour lines - 0 is the decision boundary
contours = ax.contour(x0_grid, x1_grid, decision_vals, linewidths=2, levels=6, cmap='seismic')
ax.clabel(contours)
ax.axis(ax_lims)

#
# Visualise in 3D
#
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6)).add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.view_init(azim=5, elev=20)
ax.set(xlabel='feature 0', ylabel='feature 1', zlabel='decision function')

ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], clf.decision_function(X), c=y, cmap='coolwarm')
ax.plot_surface(x0_grid, x1_grid, decision_vals,
                facecolors=plt.get_cmap('coolwarm')(decision_vals), cmap='coolwarm',
                alpha=0, linewidth=0.2)
```